# JSF Primefaces datatable in cell editMode not sending the edited value to the managed bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have two primefaces dataTables. The first show the instances of a MainEntity.
The second one show a list of Words (just strings) associated with the selected MainEntity on the first datatable.

The printscreen illustrates what I mean.

My problem is, when I edit a string on the Word List, my listener method won't receive the new value. In fact, when I call the `event.getNewValue()` method, I get old value.

What am I missing?

I'm using JavaServer Faces 2.2, Primefaces 5.0 and Spring Framework 4.0.3.

Thanks in advance for any help.

The code for the xhtml, the managed bean and the MainEntity are as follows:

> mainEntity.xhtml:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="mainEntityForm">
        <p:panelGrid columns="1" fullPage="true" id="dashboard">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h2>MainEntity Table</h2>
            </f:facet>
            <p:panel>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    MainEntity List
                    <p:commandButton value="New MainEntity"
                        actionListener="#{mainEntityController.createMainEntityDialog}"
                        styleClass="header-button">
                        <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" update=":mainEntityForm:mainEntityTable" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </f:facet>
                <p:dataTable id="mainEntityTable" var="mainEntity" value="#{mainEntityController.mainEntities}"
                    editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="cellMainEntity"
                    selectionMode="single" selection="#{mainEntityController.selectedMainEntity}"
                    rowKey="#{mainEntity.id}" tableStyle="width:auto">

                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":mainEntityForm:stringGrid :mainEntityForm:entityAGrid :mainEntityForm:entityBGrid" />
                    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{mainEntityController.onEditMainEntity}" update=":mainEntityForm:mainEntityTable" />

                    <p:column headerText="ID">
                        <h:outputText value="#{mainEntity.id}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Name">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText id="nameOutput" value="#{mainEntity.name}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <h:inputText id="atyInput" value="#{mainEntity.qty}" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Commands">
                        <p:commandButton title="Remove MainEntity" icon="ui-icon-trash"
                            actionListener="#{mainEntityController.deleteMainEntity(mainEntity)}"
                            update=":mainEntityForm:mainEntityTable" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:panel>
            <p:panelGrid fullPage="true" id="mainEntityDetail">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="4">
                            <h2>MainEntity Detail</h2>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </f:facet>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:panel>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Word List
                                <p:commandButton value="New Word"
                                        actionListener="#{mainEntityController.addNewWord()}"
                                        styleClass="header-button"
                                        update=":mainEntityForm:wordGrid">
                                </p:commandButton>
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:dataTable id="wordGrid" var="word"
                                value="#{mainEntityController.selectedMainEntity.wordList}"
                                tableStyle="width:auto" editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="cellWord">

                                <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{mainEntityController.onEditWord}" />

                                <p:column headerText="Word">
                                    <p:cellEditor>
                                        <f:facet name="output">
                                            <h:outputText id="wordOutput" value="#{word}" />
                                        </f:facet>
                                        <f:facet name="input">
                                            <h:inputText id="wordInput" value="#{word}" />
                                        </f:facet>
                                    </p:cellEditor>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Commands">
                                    <p:commandButton title="Remove Word"
                                        icon="ui-icon-trash"
                                        actionListener="#{mainEntityController.removeWord(word)}"
                                        update=":mainEntityForm:wordGrid" />
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
                        </p:panel>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

> MainEntityController.java (managed bean):

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MainEntityController {

    //...

    private MainEntity selectedMainEntity;

    public List<MainEntity> mainEntities;

    //...

    public MainEntity getSelectedMainEntity(){
        return selectedMainEntity;
    }

    public void setSelectedMainEntity(MainEntity mainEntity){
        this.selectedMainEntity = mainEntity;
    }

    //...

    public void onEditWord(CellEditEvent event) {
        Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

        if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {

            // THE PROBLEM IS HERE
            // I NEVER ACTUALLY REACH THIS CODE
            // newValue is always equal to oldValue!

            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            String word = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{word}", String.class);
            System.out.println(newValue);
            System.out.println(word);

            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Word Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

> MainEntity.java:

```
@Entity
public class MainEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(
                name="MainEntity_Word",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName="id")
            )
    @Column(name = "word")
    private Set<String> wordList;

    //...

    public void addWord(String word) {
        this.wordList.add(word);
    }

    public void removeWord(String word) {
        this.wordList.remove(word);
    }

    public Set<String> getWordList() {
        return wordList;
    }

    public void setWordList(Set<String> wordList) {
        this.wordList = wordList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `implements Serializable` to both your entity class and session bean. You need to serialize objects when you have to pass and retrieve them over the wire.

Comment: @Tiny Sorry for the typo. It's actually JSF. I just corrected the question title. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: @Sujan Thanks again for tring to help. I'll try it and come back with the results.

Comment: @Sujan It didn't work. But thanks anyway for trying to help.

Comment: @mateuscpf What did you do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working.

I suspected of the String immutable nature and what I did was to encapsulate the 'word' in a class like the following:

```
public class Word {
    private String word;

    Word (String word) {
        this.setWord(word);
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return this.word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }
}
```

After that, I also had to create a set inside the managed bean (controller) to hold the set of words, like 'private Set managedWordList;'.

I also changed the getter for the list, inside the managed bean, to convert from the String set to a Word set like:

```
public Set<Word> getWordList() {
    if (this.selectedMainEntity != null){
        this.wordList = new HashSet<Word>();
        for (String word : this.selectedMainEntity.getWordList()) {
            this.wordList.add(new Word(word));
        }
    }
    return this.wordList;
}
```

Finally, I changed the dataTable to reference the new set. From:

```
<p:dataTable ... value="#{mainEntityController.selectedMainEntity.wordList}"... />
```

To:

```
<p:dataTable ... value="#{mainEntityController.wordList}"... />
```

And only then I got it to work as I expected.

Comment: I think there is a bracket missing from <p:dataTable ... value="#mainEntityController.wordList}"... />

It should be <p:dataTable ... value="#{mainEntityController.wordList}"... />

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<h:inputText id="wordInput" value="#{word}" />
```

to

```
<p:inputText id="wordInput" value="#{word}" />
```

or

```
<h:inputText id="wordInput" value="#{word}" >
<p:ajax event="change" process="@this"/>
</h:inputText>
```

You need to *ajaxify* the input component, and at last update the outputText component.

**Edited**:

change this column :

```
<p:column headerText="Word" >
<p:cellEditor>
<f:facet name="output">
<h:outputText id="wordOutput" value="#{word}" />
</f:facet>
<f:facet name="input">
<h:inputText id="wordInput" value="#{word}" />
</f:facet>
</p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

to

```
<p:column headerText="Word" >
<p:cellEditor>
<f:facet name="output">
<h:outputText id="wordOutput" value="#{word}" />
</f:facet>
<f:facet name="input">
<p:inputText id="wordInput" value="#{word}" >
<p:ajax event="change" update="wordOutput" />
</p:inputText>
</f:facet>
</p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

**Edit 2** :

From [Chapter 24 Introduction to the Java Persistence API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnbpz/index.html)

> If an entity instance be passed by value as a detached object, such as
>   through a session bean’s remote business interface, the class must
>   implement the Serializable interface.

Comment: I tried both the solutions you proposed, but it still doesn't work. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks again Sujan, but it's still not working. I see what you've done. You kinda merged the two solutions you've proposed before and added the `update="wordOutput"` to the `p:ajax` tag. The merge I had actually tried already, but the update property (I tried it, as you suggested) didn't occur to me. Anyway, it still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by update property didn't occur to me ? And did you try to update after the ajax cellEdit event ? `<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{mainEntityController.onEditWord}" update="wordGrid" />`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I meant I didn't try it before you suggesting it. And yes, I did try it, and it also does not work. Sorry again.

Comment: I'm sorry I seem to be unable to spot the mistake, this is puzzling me. Could it be due to unserialized entities ? Might be.