# Primefaces' DataTable edit not showing new value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have been struggling for a few days now with Primefaces' DataTable not showing the new value after editing a cell.

I have looked for answers to this, but not found anything that I can relate to -- most of the time it seems to be about using strings instead of objects, but in my case I am using an object (for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812170/jsf-primefaces-datatable-in-cell-editmode-not-sending-the-edited-value-to-the-ma)).

The application I am developing shows the content of a Course entity from the database where Name, Year, Term and Active (if it is current or not) are displayed. Name, Year and Term are together the primary key. When in the data table, I can can select and edit the cells but the problem arises when I press return (or change cell). The object `event.getNewValue();` still returns the old value.

```
<p:dataTable var="oneCourse" value="#{courseManager.courses}" paginator="true" rows="5" selectionMode="single" selection="#{courseManager.courseSelection}" 
        rowKey="#{oneCourse.id}" editable="true" editMode="cell" paginatorPosition="bottom" class="dataWidth" widgetVar="cellCourse">

            <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{courseManager.onCellEdit}" update=":form:msgs" />

            <p:column headerText="Kursnamn">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{oneCourse.id.courseName}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <h:inputText value="#{oneCourse.id.courseName}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="År">
                <h:outputText value="#{oneCourse.id.year}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Termin">
                <h:outputText value="#{oneCourse.id.term}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Aktiv">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{oneCourse.active}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{oneCourse.active}">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="0" />
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="1" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>     
</p:dataTable>
```

Sorry for the Swedish...

The managed bean is a bit of a mess and contains code for working with both the front end and the configuration parts of my application. I paste it all as I suspect that I might have done something stupied concerning the problem somewhere where I have not looked...

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CourseManager implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 240902154191546462L;

@EJB
private CourseBean theCourses;

private Course courseSelection;

public CourseManager() {}

private List<String> durationList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
        "5 min",
        "10 min",
        "15 min",
        "20 min",
        "30 min",
        "45 min",
        "60 min",
        "90 min",
        "120 min"
        ));

private List<String> activityList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
        "Kursansvar",
        "Planering",
        "Handledning",
        "Föreläsning",
        "Planera föreläsning",
        "Hålla labb",
        "Labbkonstruktion",
        "Labbrättning",
        "Tentakonstruktion",
        "Tentarättning"
        ));

private String activity;

private String duration;

private String selectedCourse;

private String currCourse;
private String currTerm;
private int currYear;
private int currDuration;

public List<String> getCourseList() {
    List<Course> listOfCourses = theCourses.getListOfCourses();
    List<String> courseList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < listOfCourses.size(); i++)
    {
        if(listOfCourses.get(i).getActive()!=0)
        {
            String theCourse = listOfCourses.get(i).getId().getCourseName() + " " + listOfCourses.get(i).getId().getTerm() + " " + listOfCourses.get(i).getId().getYear();
            courseList.add(theCourse);
        }
    }

    return courseList;
}

List<Course> courses = null;

/*public void setCourses(List<Course> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
}*/


public List<Course> getCourses() {
    courses = theCourses.getListOfCourses();
    return courses;
}

public String getSelectedCourse() {
    return selectedCourse;
}

public void setSelectedCourse(String selectedCourse) {
    this.selectedCourse = selectedCourse;
}

public String getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(String duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}

public List<String> getDurationList() {
    return durationList;
}

public String getActivity() {
    return activity;
}

public void setActivity(String activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public List<String> getActivityList() {
    return activityList;
}

public void result() throws IOException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if(selectedCourse!=null || duration!=null || activity!=null ) {
        String[] parts = selectedCourse.split(" ");
        currCourse = parts[0];
        currTerm = parts[1];
        currYear = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        String[] durationParts = duration.split(" ");
        currDuration = Integer.parseInt(durationParts[0]);

        CourseActivity ca = new CourseActivity();

        ca.setName(currCourse);
        ca.setTerm(currTerm);
        ca.setYear(currYear);
        ca.setActivity(activity);
        ca.setDuration(currDuration);

        try {
            theCourses.addCourseActivity(ca);
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Inlagt!",  duration + " minuter inlagt för " + activity + " på kursen " + parts[0] + " " + parts[1] + parts[2]) );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Ett fel har uppstått!",  "Det gick inte att lägga in i databasen.") );
        }           
    }
    else
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Ett fel!",  "Inte allt var valt!") );
}

public Course getCourseSelection() {
    return courseSelection;
}

public void setCourseSelection(Course courseSelection) {
    this.courseSelection = courseSelection;
}

public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

    if(newValue != null) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}       
}
```

As is visible, I have tried to use the tutorial on DataTable Edit from the Showcase of Primefaces, but my results are not the same... I have also tried to use RowEdit, but the same effect -- my new value is never recognised. It is there somewhere, however, because as long as I am in the same session, when I select the same cell again the new value is displayed in the cell editor.

Any help would be much appreciated! I have been stuck for several days trying out several approaches, but always with the same result. If I cannot solve this, with your help, I will try to do it with out PrimeFaces...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143401/event-getobject-in-row-editing-for-primefaces-sends-the-old-value-to-the-bean ?

Comment: At first I did not see the connection, but yes -- that was it! An enormous amount of thanks to you, @JaqenH'ghar!

Comment: You're welcome.. Calling the DB in a getter (as I think you do) is always bad in JSF :-) It will be called several times just to show the page once. Better to populate in @init or with lazy load (check if list is null, if so then load and set for next time)